# What's the reason for this failure in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, bigdata

[image]

It occurred frequently in my hadoop job when executing the reduce task.
**Some reasons for this problem may be that the reducer did not write the context for a long time, and so you need to add context.progress() in your code. But in my reduce function, the context is written frequently.** Here is my reduce function:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws 
      IOException,InterruptedException{
            Text s=new Text();
            Text exist=new Text("e");
            ArrayList<String> T=new ArrayList<String>();
            for(Text val:values){
                String value=val.toString();
                T.add(value);
                s.set(key.toString()+"-"+value);
                context.write(s,exist);
            }
            Text need=new Text("n");
            for(int i=0;i<T.size();++i){
                String a=T.get(i);
                for(int j=i+1;j<T.size();++j){
                    String b=T.get(j);
                    int f=a.compareTo(b);
                    if(f<0){
                        s.set(a+"-"+b);
                        context.write(s,need);
                    }
                    if(f>0){
                        s.set(b+"-"+a);
                        context.write(s,need);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

You can see that the context is written frequently in the loop.
What's the reason for this failure? And how can I handle it?

Comment: does job finish correctly or it interrupts because of these failures?

Comment: It still runs until 100% and ends with failure.@AdamSkywalker

Comment: i'd first open applicaton UI and check application logs from the machines with failed reducers. they can contain some clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task is taking more than 600 seconds to complete.

From Apache documentation [page](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml), you can find more details.

> mapreduce.task.timeout
>
> 600000 ( **default value in milli second**s)
>
> The number of milliseconds before a task will be terminated if it neither reads an input, writes an output, nor updates its status string. A value of 0 disables the timeout.

Possible options:

1. Finetune your application to complete the task with in 600 seconds

   OR
2. Increase timeout for parameter `mapreduce.task.timeout` in **mapred-site.xml**